# What does the max packet loss metric mean in the Google Meet audit log?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm looking at the docs for the audit log [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet). There is a metric for `video_recv_packet_loss_max`, which claims to be "the maximum packet loss for received video streams (percent)". Is packet loss measured every X seconds and then they takes the max over all intervals? If so, how long are these intervals? Thanks!

Comment: Indeed there's no further information, I'll try to investigate as an extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

### `video_recv_packet_loss_max` is the highest amount (in percentage) of packet loss for received video streams

By **highest amount** I mean the packet loss that occurs in the connection between one user and the meeting and this is NOT measured every X seconds, minutes or hours but the meeting duration.